# Creating Columns after Refreshing Query in Excel then adding formulas

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

So I have this VBA code which I am trying to piece together...

```
Sub GradeColumn()

Sheets("Query").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("K2").Select
Range("K2").FormulaR1C1 = "Difference in date"
Range("K3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[Posting Date]-[Expected Receipt Date]"
Range("L2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Grade"
Range("L3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaLocal = "=IF([Difference in date]<2,""A"",IF([Difference in date]=2,""B"",IF([Difference in date]=3,""C"",IF([Difference in date]=4,""D"",""F"")))"
Sheets("Pivot Table").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

End Sub
```

What I want it to do is, Refresh the Query Table, Create two columns in the Query table one named Difference in Date with a Formula in the column and the other named Grade with a grading scale formula in that column.

I keep getting an

> Application-defined or object-defined error

in the grading scale formula.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: It's likely that the table field names are misspelled in your formula. Try writing the formula manually on the sheet and click the cells to create the reference perfectly. Then paste the completed formula into your Macro.

Comment: I guess that you don't have enought right brackets? :) You have 4 if's and only 3 ")))"

Comment: Additionaly instead of FormulaLocal use Formula. FormulaLocal is to define formula in local language (for non-english excel versions).

Comment: TomJohnRiddle, you were exactly right.. as simple as missing that bracket... wish I would have seen that a while ago.